# AWR Report for execution of PL/SQL with multiple queries

Tags: oracle, plsql, awr

How does a PLSQL script execute?

Currently, I am confused with the AWR report analysis of a PLSQL script.

I see two different SQLIDs, one for the PLSQL SQL script and another for a query executed by the PLSQL.

Is it expected to have two different SQLIDs, or some other process is running the other sql?

Answer (score 0):

Just we are taking small example for Top running session for CPu.
[image]

we are checking same sqlid clicked then we are able to data for same.
[image]